# Bash one liner, SED, every used character

Tags: bash

I need one liners for search every used character in document.

For example:

IN: aaabbccaa//..**

OUT: abc/.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed 's/./&\n/g' /etc/passwd | sort -u | tr -d '\n'
```

Output:

```
 -,:/()0123456789aAbBcdDefgGhHiIJkKlLmMnNoOpPqrRsStTuvwxy
```